# Why Do These Dates Result In 'Invalid Dates' After Being Fetched From MongoDb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

I simply want to add one day and then represent 12:00AM on that new day using Moment.Js.  However, whenever I do this and then save it, MongoDB returns the date as `Invalid Date`...  Why?

```
 date = new Date(Date.UTC(2000, 2, 13));
 date = moment.utc( date );
 date = date.add(1, 'd');
```

Before Saving, The Date Looks LIke This: `date: Sun Feb 13 2000 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)`

How The Date Looks In My Database: `2000-02-14 00:00:00.000Z`

But, it shows up as invalid when fetched from the database:

```
{ 
  date: "Invalid Date"
  day: "02/13/2000"
  full_date: "02/13/2000 24"
  hour: "24"
}
```

Further, all days constructed like this will result in `Invalid Dates`

Answer (score 1):

`2000-02-14 00:00:00.000Z` is not a valid date format in Javascript.

[ECMA Date Time String Format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ
```

Ref [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

It is missing the `T` as in time element.

Try this in your console:

```
>> (new Date("2000-02-14 00:00:00.000Z")).toString()
<< "Invalid Date"
```

vs.

```
>> (new Date("2000-02-14T00:00:00.000Z")).toString()
<< "Mon Feb 14 2000 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)"
```

---

Note, some browsers accept the former, such as Chrome, but it is non standard and by that follows pain as usual.

Firefox is rather strict on date.

Comment: Thanks, but why doesn't Moment.js return a valid Date Format?  Or, how can I get a valid date format from Moment?

Comment: @ac360: ERR. My comment became a mess. Shortly: I do not know Moment and scrambled the tags

Comment: You know what, all of the date records in my MongoDB do not include the 'T', they look similar: 2000-01-01 02:00:00.000Z.  Yet, only the date records at Midnight: 2000-01-02 00:00:00.000Z return as Invalid Dates

Comment: @ac360: Hmmm. The millennium scare finally struck ... ;P only shortly over and a bit delayed